# How to create a TCP tunnel in windows to allow remote->local connections in NAT environment?

Tags: windows-7, tcpip, tunnel, nat, dynamic-dns

So I know about SSH tunneling via a remote Linux server to reach sites which are blocked in my local network. My question is the other way around:

I have a webserver running locally, which I can access inside the local network. I however cannot reach it from outside as I'm in a NAT environment. I COULD forward a port on the router to the specific machine - but I am not able to do this (large company network).

I know it is possible to remotely connect to my machine through NAT via e.g. Skype (NAT hole punching) or even TeamViewer (connecting through third party site) - all they are doing is tunneling the connection, right?

How do I set up this kind of tunnel with some software? I am assuming I always need a third party server to set up the tunneling? How to do so with Windows? What is the simplest way? Any service like DynDNS which (besides linking the domain to the IP) let's me tunnel a connection, so that myspecialdomain.example.org leads to a machine within the NAT environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a VPN remotely and get the server inside the network to join it. This VPN could be on a dedicated system, or on the remote system you're trying to connect from, provided that system is accessible externally.

Comment: So basically something like Hamachi, but do I have a simple URL (mycomputer.example.org) to access the computer? I don't want to install proprietary software on the client, but provide a simple shareable URL (Basically it is for showing my local DEV server quickly to someone else)

Comment: If you have an external webserver, say on a VPS, you could use that as the VPN (I'm thinking OpenVPN rather than Hamachi) and then setup a reverse proxy on the webserver on the VPS to the internal VPN address of the machine you're trying to get to.

Internal Box <- {VPN <- Reverse Proxy <- External Server} <- External Requests

Comment: Reverse Proxy is worth looking into, thanks for the keyword.